# Proof that if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then $\inf(A\cap B)\geq\max\{\inf(A),\inf(B)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have to prove that if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then $\inf(A\cap B) \geq \max\{\inf(A,\inf(B)\}$

The proof in my lecture notes is the following[image: Solution]

However I developed a much shorter proof and I don't think it is actually necessary to prove it that way. Do you think mine works as well?

Without loss of generality suppose $\inf(A)\geq \inf(B)$ so that $\max\{\inf(A),\inf(B)\}=\inf(A)$.

Take an arbitrary $c\in A\cap B$. By definition $c\in A$ and $c\in B$. Hence $c\geq \inf(A)\geq\inf(B)$. So that $\inf(A)$ and $\inf(B)$ are lower bounds for $A\cap B$. Therefore by definition of infimum $\inf(A\cap B) \geq \inf(A)\geq\inf(B)$ and in particular $\inf(A \cap B) \geq \max\{\inf(A),\inf(B)\}$. The same holds if the first assumption is inverted.

Comment: It is the same proof. You have omitted the discussion about the existence. That's okay. The lecture note has just some more explanations, which is also okay and common for introductory courses.